# How to perform Struct Serialization in C# with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a requirement in which i want to serialize various properties like `System.Windows.FontWeight,FontStretch` and other such structs with the help of `JavaScriptSerializer`.

But it is giving empty json value of above properties on serializing the object having struct data type properties to json.

Any generic solution to the above problem??

Thanks

Dhiraj V